# Angular 8 DexExtreme dx-list rows and/or elements not showing properly

Tags: json, angular, rest

First, I am 99% confident that the controller through the REST API connection and into the client side view model is correct based on some debug points. Also, the `dx-list` we are using is at least detecting the correct numnber of rows based on that result. However, the contents in the rows is not showing up for some reason.

I'd like to insert four "columns" (loosely) into a list row, basically, a `key` (hidden), `label`, `weight` and whether that row `isSelected`, all part of that domain model that correctly transmitted, i.e.

```
[{key: ..., label: ..., weight: ..., isSelected: ...}, ...]
```

Now, additionally, `key` should be hidden. It could display for debugging purposes, but ultimately should be hidden. `isSelected` should be a check box, and `weight` should be a numeric edit. Lastly, `label` should be a textual label.

Currently, I've got a view something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="true">
  <dx-list [items]="strategy.strategicValues">
    <div *dxTemplate="let item of 'items'">
      <div>
        <span hidden>{{item.key}}</span>
        <div><dx-check-box [(value)]="item.isSelected"></dx-check-box></div>
        <div>
          <span>{{item.label}}</span>
          <dx-number-box [(value)]="item.weight" [min]="0" [showSpinButtons]="true" [(disabled)]="!item.isSelected"></dx-number-box>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </dx-list>
</div>
```

It looks accurate enough to me, but I'm kind of at a loss as to why the elements are not displaying properly.

Answer (score 1):

The default name of the itemTemplate is `item` and not `items`.
Try using:

```
<div *dxTemplate="let item of 'item'">
```

**Edit:**
For a custom name use the `itemTemplate` property on the dx-list element:

```
<dx-list [items]="strategy.strategicValues" itemTemplate="myTemplate">
<div *dxTemplate="let item of 'myTemplate'">
```

Comment: Huh, okay. Well, that's progress anyway. At least I am seeing data display, which is good. Now it is down to layout, that sort of thing. Is there a way to set the default name for the items? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out. Apparently, the fundamental `ng` protocol for bindings should be more like this, `[disabled]="!item.isSelected"`. Subtle, but now I understand much better.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example from the [doc](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/List/ItemTemplate/Angular/Dark/) for a custom template.

```html
<div class="list-container">
    <dx-list [items]="products" height="100%">
        <div *dxTemplate="let item of 'item'">
            <div class="product">
                <img src="{{item.ImageSrc}}" />
                <div>{{item.Name}}</div>
                <div class="price">{{item.Price | currency:'USD':'symbol':'1.0'}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </dx-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but this has nothing whatsoever to do with model bindings.